# Where can I ask about mechanisms?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask questions about how machines work, in particular about their [mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_(engineering)). For example, I want to ask about a weapon's trigger and how it acts as a lever, or how does a excavator function, I want answers to get some detail of how the mechanism works, which are the parts, and intuitive help to understand how the parts interact to obtain the goal of the machine.

I imagine that [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) could be useful.

I tried the tags [mechanism](/questions/tagged/mechanism), [mechanisms](/questions/tagged/mechanisms), [machine](/questions/tagged/machine), [machines](/questions/tagged/machines) and they have extremely low popularity (less than 5 results).

However, the tag [[mechanical-engineering]](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering) yields 885 results. I think I may need to ask questions on this site using this tag. Do you agree?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have already identified the Engineering Stack Exchange as a likely site for your question, and to have reviewed its tags and some of its Q&As.

Consequently, I would recommend that you ask there whichever of your questions you think is likely to be the best received, and watch it carefully to ensure that is the case.  If it attracts comments, downvotes or gets placed On Hold, then quickly address them.

In fact it looks like you have already asked one question there ([Do longer gun's barrel improve accuracy?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11962/do-longer-guns-barrel-improve-accuracy)) and that appears to have attracted a quality answer so I think you should follow your instincts.